# how to get the user logged in in community

Tags: visualforce, community

I need to get the Id of the user logged in community for `Visualforce Page`. How can I get the login user in salesforce community and use in `Visualforce Page`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Visualforce`, you can reference the `User` [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm).

```
{!$User.Id}
```

In `Apex`, `UserInfo` [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) should work just fine in the context of communities:

```
Id runningUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
```